# Problem: Octomap is not working with Kinect Pointcloud

Tags: octomap, octomap-mapping, 3d-slam, 3dslam, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everyone,

I am using kinect for creating pointcloud and passing `/camera/depth/point` from kinect `freenect_camera` to `octomap_server` by `remapping octomap cloud_in point cloud to /camera/depth/point`.  Everything is working fine, Kinect is publishing  proper pointcloud, successfully remapping from cloud_in to /camera/depth/point.

```
Octomap_server is publishing all topics mentioned in [Octomap_server](http://wiki.ros.org/octomap_server).
```

I tried to visualize using `rviz` but I am not getting anything in `markerArray and Map` I also try to visualize using `topic` but nothing is coming. Plz help me to rectify this.

If I missed any step for generating 3D occupancy grid map plz let me know, Is there any Slam exist (except rgbdslam and compatible in Ros Hydro) which publishes pointcloud2, and can be inputed to octomap.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208954/problem:-octomap-is-not-working-with-kinect-pointcloud/) by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2015-05-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you changed the topic in the MotionPlanning plugin from "/planning_scene" to "/move_group/monitored_planning_scene" ?

---

Originally posted by [bridos](https://answers.ros.org/users/18758/bridos/) with karma: 26 on 2015-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-05-11**:
I didn't do this, actually I didn't find proper document for this. In [Octomap_server](http://wiki.ros.org/octomap_server), they only mentioned that it will subscribe pointcloud2, can you do me favor plz give me proper link for octomap, and tell me other requirements to change.

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-05-12**:
MotionPlanning plugin is not there.. tell me the process.

**Comment by [bridos](https://answers.ros.org/users/18758/bridos/) on 2015-05-12**:
In RVIZ if you click the "Add" button, you can add the MotionPlanning plugin. To get octomap, you have to run sudo apt-get install ros-your-distro-octomap, there are some other packages also for octomap (in terminal and while you have typed the above command press tab twice to see them.

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-05-12**:
Everything is installed already, I searched plugins in rviz but it is not there. Is there any way to add/install particular plugin in rviz.

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-05-13**:
I think u r using moveit! driver. but I dont have ros compatible robot. I am writting code for moving it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need a transformation tree for octomap to work properly, are you using one?

---

Originally posted by [RodrigoLG](https://answers.ros.org/users/20409/rodrigolg/) with karma: 21 on 2015-05-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-05-11**:
Thanx for your reply..
Should I write another program for `/tf` node or something else? according to the ROS page, It is subscribing `cloud_in` pointcloud. What should I do for this.

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-05-13**:
can u post ur transform tree in aswer and how to use that?
Have I to write simple frame transform node for this?

**Comment by [nitekrawler](https://answers.ros.org/users/20470/nitekrawler/) on 2016-10-23**:
@KDROS, did you ever figure it out?